# jquery event loss on ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Let's say that I have some HTML content in which I have some textareas. This HTML content is loaded through Ajax after performing some kind of action (like a button click or something). The problem that I have is that I lose all kinds of jQuery events that were bond to my textareas (like the `.change` event or something, so if I do something like:

```
$('.my_textarea').change(function(){
    alert('TEST');
});
```

My alert does not display because my textarea has been loaded with Ajax. Does anybody have any idea why this problem happens and how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: read the jQuery FAQ section of docs. There are also 100's of posts on this same topic ... did you not look at some of the `Related` links in sidebar??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).on('change', '.my_textarea', function(){
    alert('TEST');
});
```

Just replace `document` with the closest static ( not loaded via Ajax ) parent of your textarea